# Using SSE to send data from server to frontend, but PHP hangs server and causes it to freeze, what is wrong with my implementation?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-tag-manager, server-sent-events

I currently have a WordPress website which uses `Learndash` with many courses and lessons. I am trying to track custom events using certain `Learndash` hooks for when users complete course or lessons etc.

Currently, I have an implementation where I store the events data to my database from the backend, then using SSE, I send these events to the frontend to push to **Google tag manager** using `dataLayer.push`.

For some reason, my code seems to crash the server as it runs maybe for about 1 day, then all of a sudden, the CPU spikes to 99% and I get a 504 error. I believe it is something to do with the implementation of SSE causing this, but I am unsure what it might be. Here is my code.

The PHP code…

```
public function start()
  {

    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(0);

    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream; charset=utf-8');
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, #proxy-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . time());
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');

    sleep(3);

    if ($this->lock->isLocked()) {

      $this->log->error('Duplicate SSE session', [
        'user_id' => get_current_user_id(),
      ]);

      return new WP_Error(
        'duplicate_sse_connection',
        'Only one active SSE connection allowed',
        ['status' => 429]
      );
    }

    $this->lock->lock();

    register_shutdown_function(
      fn () => $this->lock->unlock()
    );

    while (true) {

        if(connection_aborted()) {
          break;
        }

        wp_cache_flush();

        $events = $this->events->getAll();

        if (is_wp_error($events)) break;

        /**
         * Sending more than 1 SSE message at a time causes weird and unexpected behaviour
         */
        if (!empty($events) && isset($events[0])) {

          $event = $events[0];

          $attempt = $event->attempt();

          if (is_wp_error($attempt)) continue;

          $data = ['id' => $event->id, 'payload' => $event->data];

          $json = json_encode($data);

          $id = $event->id;

          $msg = $this->makeMessage($json, $id);

          $this->sendMessage($msg);

        } else {

          $this->sendMessage(":keep-alive\n\n");

          sleep(1);

        }

        // if (empty($events)) $this->sendMessage(":keep-alive\n\n");

        // $this->log->info('Loop is alive with heartbeat 2');

        sleep(1);

        // we deliberately use locks with short expiry  to account for
        // fatal crashes, timeouts, unexpected events, etc.

        // refresh lock if it has expired
        if ($this->lock->hasExpired()) {
          $this->lock->lock();
        }
          
    } 
  }

  /**
   * Make message compatible with Server Sent Events format
   */
  protected function makeMessage(
    string $data,
    ?string $id = null
  ): string {

    $msg = '';

    $msg .= sprintf('data: %s%s', $data, "\n");

    if (isset($id)) $msg .= sprintf('id: %s%s', $id, "\n");

    $msg .= sprintf('retry: %s%s', 6000, "\n");

    $msg .= sprintf('%s%s', "\n", "\n");

    return $msg;
  }

  /**
   * Send Server Sent Events to the frontend
   * @link https://javascript.info/server-sent-events
   */
  protected function sendMessage(string $msg): void
  {
    echo $msg;

    if (ob_get_contents()) ob_end_clean();

    flush();

    sleep(1);
  }
```

The frontend end code...

```
import { Schemas, Types } from '../Schemas';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    gtm?: Types['GTM'];
    dataLayer?: {
      push: (event: Types['Event']) => void;
    };
  }
}

let sse: EventSource | null = null;
let retryInProgress: boolean = false;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (!document.body.classList.contains('logged-in')) {
    return console.warn('sse disabled, no active user session');
  }
  if (!window.gtm) {
    return console.error('Missing window.gtm');
  }
  const gtm = Schemas.GTM.safeParse(window.gtm);
  if (gtm.success) {
    startSSE(gtm.data);
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      unlock(gtm.data);
    });
  }
});


function startSSE(gtm: Types['GTM']): void {

  if(sse !== null) {
    console.log('SSE connection is already active');
    return;
  }

  const url = new URL(gtm.events);
  // without this, you will get 403 error
  url.searchParams.append('_wpnonce', gtm.nonce);

  // sse = server-sent events
  sse = new EventSource(url.href);

  sse.addEventListener('open', (e) => {
    console.log('sse has started');
  });

  sse.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
    if (sse.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) {
      console.log('sse connection closed manually');
      gtm.retry++;
      window.gtm = gtm;
      // increase timeout with each retry to avoid spamming
      setTimeout(() => startSSE(gtm), gtm.retry * gtm.wait);

      // if (!retryInProgress) {
      //   retryInProgress = true;

      //   gtm.retry++;
      //   window.gtm = gtm;

      //   setTimeout(() => {
      //     retryInProgress = false;
      //     startSSE(gtm);
      //   }, gtm.retry * gtm.wait);
      // }

    }

    if (sse.readyState !== EventSource.CLOSED) console.error(e);
  });

  sse.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    // https://web.dev/eventsource-basics/#a-word-on-security
    if (e.origin !== window.location.origin) return;

    let json = null;

    try {
      json = JSON.parse(e.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('failed to parse json');
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }

    if (!json) return console.log('unexpected state');

    const sse = Schemas.Message(Schemas.Event);

    const msg = sse.safeParse(json);

    if (!msg.success) {
      console.error('failed to parse SSE message');
      console.error(e.data);
      console.error(msg.error);
      return;
    }

    const {
      data: { id, payload: event },
    } = msg;

    const data = new FormData();

    data.set('id', id);

    const init: RequestInit = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
    };

    fetch(url, init).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok && window.dataLayer) {
        window.dataLayer.push(event);
      }
    });
  });
}

function unlock(gtm: Types['GTM']): void {
  const url = new URL(gtm.unlock);
  url.searchParams.append('_wpnonce', gtm.nonce);
  const data = new FormData();
  data.set('_wpnonce', gtm.nonce);
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
  });
  console.log('closing sse connection');
  // we do not need to wait for this as sse lock has timeout
}

export {};
```

As you can see from the PHP code, I have implemented locks to prevent multiple connection per user when then try to open more than 1 browser. I have also on the frontend a way to check if there is an SSE connection to prevent more than 1 connection but for some reason, it still causes a crash.

I have tried locking to prevent more than 1 connection. I have changed the set_time_limit to 1 day or half a day to time it out, but this does nothing. I have read through different threads and still can't find a definitive answer.

If anyone can offer some assistance, I would appreciate it. Thanks